# Receiving an Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

Here is the exception I am receiving:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Here is my code:

```
public class LeagueTable extends JTable {

    public static final Dimension INITIAL_SIZE = new Dimension(500, 300);
    public final String[] columnNames;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;

    public LeagueTable(){

        DatabaseConnector listOfTeams = new DatabaseConnector();
        columnNames = new String[]{"Teams", "Goal Difference", "Points", "Verdict"};
        Object[][] data = listOfTeams.teamResults.toArray(new Object[listOfTeams.teamResults.size()][]);
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model){@Override
                                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

            return false;
        }};

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(INITIAL_SIZE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(pane);
    }

    public String[] getStringArray() {
        return columnNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: This looks funny to me: `Object[][] data = listOfTeams.teamResults.toArray(new Object[listOfTeams.teamResults.size()][]);`. You never really create a 2D array that I can see here.

Comment: Its the data = listOfTeams.teamResults.toArray(new Object[listOfTeams.teamResults.size()][]); line which is causing the issues. teamResults is an ArrayList which I am trying to change into a 2d array so I can store it in JTable.

Comment: `LeagueTable extends JTable`  Why does this class extend table?  I have witten or worked with code for ..100s of (Swing based) tables.  Commonly we'll create custom renderers, or use custom table models, but I've never seen a good case for extending table itself.  BTW - For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was right, the line:

```
Object[][] data = listOfTeams.teamResults.toArray(new 
         Object[listOfTeams.teamResults.size()][]);
```

Is causing your problem, and this makes sense since you are not in fact creating a 2 D array on this line of code, but only a one dimensional array. You need to either create *row* objects that are arrays of objects for this to work or not use the DefaultTableModel. If you want to stick with DefaultTableModel, then you will likely need to use a for loop to fill your array prior to trying to use it in this constructor.